# Undefined reference SDL - Probably bad command to compile

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compilation, sdl-2

I'm trying to build my SDL 2.0 hello world:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  -> SDL_Init undefined reference.
```

or this:

```
gcc -I C:\MinGW\include\SDL2 -o test test.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -> Still undefined reference
```

or this:

```
gcc -I "C:\MinGW\include\SDL2" -o test test.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -> Nope
```

or this:

```
gcc -I C:\MinGW\include\SDL2 -L C:\MinGW\lib -o test test.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

or the same with `""`.

I can't find a single easy-to-read documentation about how to compile a simple code.

Comment: Is the bitness matching?

Comment: You need to include the actual compiler output. Typically the undefined reference is the problem, preceding that should be XXX not found.